can not click on next page button with Selenium and Python
with Python an Selenium I am trying get data from a web page.
This works fine for first page, but there are more than one page.
I can already grab the number of pages.
7 in this example. See: span class="paging-index-span"
What fails is to press the "next page button": input class="ui-icon-arrow-next-home"
I cannot find any code to successfully press this button.
I have worked with AI to support me but it did not work. This is why I am bothering you.
This should be the relevant portion of the HTML code:
<div id="user-list-list-paging-area">  
 <div class="ui-icon-btn-white paging-icon-div">  
 <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-btn-d ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">
 <input class="ui-icon-arrow-first ui-disabled" data-inline="true" data-theme="d" type="button" value=""/>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-icon-btn-white paging-icon-div">
 <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-btn-d ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">
 <input class="ui-icon-arrow-back-home ui-disabled" data-inline="true" data-theme="d" type="button" value=""/>
 </div>
</div>
<span class="paging-index-span"> 
 <span style="font-size: x-large;">1</span> 
 <span class="page-index cursor-pointer" data-index="2">2</span> 
 <span class="page-index cursor-pointer" data-index="3">3</span> 
 <span class="page-index cursor-pointer" data-index="4">4</span> 
 <span class="page-index cursor-pointer" data-index="5">5</span> 
 ...
 <span class="page-index cursor-pointer" data-index="7">7</span> 
</span>
<div class="ui-icon-btn-white paging-icon-div">
 <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-btn-d ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">
 <input class="ui-icon-arrow-next-home" data-inline="true" data-theme="d" type="button" value=""/>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="ui-icon-btn-white paging-icon-div">
 <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-btn-d ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">
 <input class="ui-icon-arrow-last" data-inline="true" data-theme="d" type="button" value=""/>
 </div>
</div>

My code to access and click the button:
next_page_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ui-icon-arrow-next-home')))
next_page_button.click()

Result:
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 


No further message.

error 404 no code, no help

Are you sure that Next button isn't in an IFRAME or shadow DOM element? We can't really help with the limited info you've provided. What's the URL of the page?

I was able to grab the user info from this page which looked to me as the difficult part and now I am struggling with a simple "next page" button. The URL is: https://aquarea-service.panasonic.com/.
I have passed the login screen and on the second screen comes left hand the user info, below this user info comes the number of pages (7 in my case, which I can read) right hand a google map with the location of the user (I do not care about). I do not understand why I cannot press a simple button.
